# How do I manager multiple layout nesting levels and optional/override content_for blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the practice detailed in the RoR guides and I can't seem to figure out a solution.

Say I have 3 levels of layout; application, news, local_news. I would like to be able to provide some default values for the application layout, but then the sub layouts might want to override those.

Using the approach in RoR guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) it would seem impossible, since the sub layout content_for is defined before the application layout would be.

Is there a Rails pattern for what I'm trying to do? or is there simply a better way?

In other platforms the variables just wouldn't be read into the layout until render was called.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear: "In other platforms the variables just wouldn't be read into the layout until render was called." Partials can be used to dynamically format  any page you need using the in-context variables at page load. You can use logic or a helper to dynamically determine which  partial to call and what to display in it.

Comment: If I supply a content_for block at the application layout level and then in a sub layout supply a content_for block -- even if flush: true the application content_for block is used (because it is the last read block).

Comment: I see. I use partials mainly; I find them quite useful for customizing layout. I haven't used content_for, so I hope someone else comes along who can help.